# If list of values of first dictionary match values of second, replace list with keys of second

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries with a list of values

```
[{'name': ['TO_MATCH_1', 'TO_MATCH_2'], 'amount': ['2', '1']},
 {'name': ['TO_MATCH_3', 'TO_MATCH_2'], 'amount': ['3', '4']}]
```

If the list of values under `name` match the values of a second dictionary:

```
{'ONE': 'TO_MATCH_1',
 'TWO': 'TO_MATCH_2',
 'THREE': 'TO_MATCH_3',
 'FOUR': 'TO_MATCH_4'}
```

The list is to be replaced with the keys of the second.

Expected output:

```
[{'name': ['ONE', 'TWO'], 'amount': ['2', '1']},
 {'name': ['THREE', 'TWO'], 'amount': ['3', '4']}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# DATA
d1 = [{'name': ['TO_MATCH_1', 'TO_MATCH_2'], 'amount': ['2', '1']},
 {'name': ['TO_MATCH_3', 'TO_MATCH_2'], 'amount': ['3', '4']}]

d2 = {'ONE': 'TO_MATCH_1',
 'TWO': 'TO_MATCH_2',
 'THREE': 'TO_MATCH_3',
 'FOUR': 'TO_MATCH_4'}
```

```
d3 = {v: k for k, v, in d2.items()}
[{k: [d3.get(x, x) for x in v] for k, v in el.items()} for el in d1]
# [{'name': ['ONE', 'TWO'], 'amount': ['2', '1']},
#  {'name': ['THREE', 'TWO'], 'amount': ['3', '4']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reverse the mapping dictionary and use it in loop to replace values:

```
r_map = {v:k for k,v in mapping.items()}
for d in lst:
    for i, name in enumerate(d['name']):
        d['name'][i] = r_map.get(name, name)
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': ['ONE', 'TWO'], 'amount': ['2', '1']}, 
 {'name': ['THREE', 'TWO'], 'amount': ['3', '4']}]
```